# Flutter, problem using InitState method and problem using setState

Tags: flutter

I have tried many things to get to call an API and get data, this has been satisfactory but I have not been able to do it from the correct method, when I do it from build it works perfectly but it is not the right place, when I try to do it in initState it simply does not it works, it doesn't even execute the print ();

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

class Post {
  final List<dynamic> data;

  Post({this.data});

  factory Post.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Post(
      data: json['response'],
    );
  }
}

class LoaderPublicity extends StatefulWidget {


  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return _LoaderPublicity();
  }
}

class _LoaderPublicity extends State<LoaderPublicity> {
  List allPublicity;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getPublicity().then((value) {
      print(allPublicity);
    });
    print(allPublicity);
  }

  //Obtener todas las publicidades desde el api
  Future<void> getPublicity() async {
    var response = await http.post(
        'http://contablenift.co:3008/consult/getGeneralPublicity',
        body: {'actividad': "Turistico", 'location': "No"});
    print('????????2');
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      setState(() {
        allPublicity = Post.fromJson(json.decode(response.body)).data;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    getPublicity();
    // TODO: implement build
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[Text('Aqui va la publicidad')],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**
Solved the problem, after going to the entire development team we realized that my phone did not have internet, happy day**

Comment: Where do you want to call `getPublicity()`? In `initState`?

Comment: yep, in initState. this function call API and update allPublicity

Comment: Why are you returning data in `getPublicity()`? I would just leave it at `setState()` and just use the variable from the class. Set the return type of `getPublicity()` to void and leave it at that.

Comment: Also, don't use `this` to call `setState()`. Remove `this` because you don't need it.

Comment: ingles: has been modified to return data to variables, paint and modify them, the current state of the function is the sum of the attempts to make it operate, what it really tries is to make it run in initState to be able to use setState

Comment: @BenjaminS. oh, ok. 
I come from React Native and React JS and this.setstate is used, thanks for the annotation

Comment: Yes but still, once you call setState, you can just use the `allPublicity` variable that should have a value. I can see that it will have the same data so why not?

Comment: It turns out that I can use setState, what I can't use is initState, I need initState to then update the variable and paint Widgets

Comment: So you're saying `initState` doesn't run?

Comment: yep. `initState` not work, print(''); no execute un this method or getPublicity()

Comment: Try adding `void` in front of `initState()`.

Comment: now print('Ok'); work, but not execute the function getPublicity(); :((((

Comment: Can you update the question with your current code? Or is that your current code and you're just not calling `getPublicity()`?

Comment: OK, updating code

Comment: You can remove the old code and again, you don't use `this` to get methods or variables. Also, since the function is asynchronous, the variable `allPublicity` won't get updated until it's complete so that's why when you print it, it's null.

Comment: I have changed my code and I have removed this, however it still does not work and it has been a long enough time for the API to respond and the variable is not repainted </ 3, I am already giving up xD

Comment: Update the code with all the `this`' removed and add a `.then` callback to the `getPublicity()` call in `initState()`. Inside the callback, print the variable and it shouldn't be null. Ex. `this.getPublicity().then((value) { print(value); });`

Comment: Run getPublicity () in iniState, when you load the app for the first time if it runs but never reaches the .then, however if I put a print arrives from the http.post this if it is shown, when it is hot reaload the app does not show again print

Comment: Hot reload only rebuilds the widget, it maintains the state therefore not calling initState() again. To get initState called, you need to hot restart the app.

Comment: Today I learned a lot from you ^^

Comment: Then the problem is http.post and it is curious because before if it showed content, it is now that it does nothing

Comment: You need to add the .then() callback IN the initState() method. Remove it in the getPublicity method.

Comment: FYI, instead of using 'hot reload' (R), you could use 'full reload' (Shirt+R) which should reinitialize all states if that is what you are looking for. It will also re-run initState.

Comment: yes, already try this, not work </3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below should work, I've added a callback in the initState method.

```
class LoaderPublicity extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return _LoaderPublicity();
  }
}

class _LoaderPublicity extends State<LoaderPublicity> {
  List allPublicity;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getPublicity().then((value) {
      print(allPublicity);
      print(value);
    });
  }

  //Obtener todas las publicidades desde el api
  Future<void> getPublicity() async {
    var response = await http.post(
        'http://contablenift.co:3008/consult/getGeneralPublicity',
        body: {'actividad': "Turistico", 'location': "No"})
    print('????????2');
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      setState(() {
        allPublicity = Post.fromJson(json.decode(response.body)).data;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[Text('Aqui va la publicidad')],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // Add listeners to this class
    getPublicity().then((response){
      print(allPublicity);
      print(response);
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        setState(() {
          allPublicity = Post.fromJson(json.decode(response.body)).data;
        });
        print(allPublicity);
      }
    });
  }

Comment: I forgot the return type of Future, my bad

Comment: Also, every time you edit the `initState` method, you need to hot restart the app.

Comment: yep, i put Future type in getPublicity()

Comment: Future getPublicity() async

Comment: Future<void>, not just future

Comment: This is becoming very rare, as I should not be so complex